# Date-picker doesn't appear when focus the entry

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm working on this control which is not working properly and i don't know where is the issue. Below you have the xaml and xaml.cs. The problem is that when i'm trying to focus on it and select a date the android's datepicker doesn't show up. It is working on xamarin forms but not on maui, apparently.

```
<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference thisControl}">
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <dt:DTEntry ParameterObject="{Binding Source={x:Reference datePickerObj}}"
                       Text="{Binding TextValue}"
                       Placeholder="{Binding PlaceHolder}"
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                       FontSize="Small" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       Focused="SsEntry_Focused"/>
            <Button   
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                    HorizontalOptions="End" 
                    Padding="10,0,10,0" 
                    Command="{Binding ClearCmd}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding TextValue, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullOrEmptyConverter}}">
                <Button.ImageSource>
                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeRegular"
                                     Glyph="{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.FaTimes}"
                                     Size="26"/>
                </Button.ImageSource>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <DatePicker IsVisible="False" x:Name="datePickerObj" Date="{Binding SelectedDateTime}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

```
private void SsEntry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentObj = sender as DTEntry;
        currentObj.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => currentObj.Unfocus());

        datePickerObj.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => datePickerObj.Focus());
        if (selectedDateTime.Year == 1900)
            (currentObj.ParameterObject as DatePicker).Date = DateTime.Now;
        else
            (currentObj.ParameterObject as DatePicker).Date = selectedDateTime;


    }
```

The behavior should be focus on the entry -> datepicker appears -> select a date -> selected date should be on entry.

Comment: Your button is covering your entry

Answer (score 2):

I can totally reproduce your issue. Nothing wrong with your code and it seems a bug. I set the *IsVisible* property of DatePicker to false and call *DatePicker.Focus()*. It's really weird that it worked well in Xamarin, even worked well on .net maui iOS but failed for Andriod.

I also find this Github issue [Fix (or don't) the behavior of calling "Focus" on Android to open the picker](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8946) , which is the same as your questions. Maybe you could follow this issue and really hope this issue could be fixed asap.